# Form data is correctly posted to email but incorrectly posted to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, zero

I have a form where people can select whether they have class on the half hour (e.g. starting or end at 12:30, for example) or whether they only classes ending on the whole hour (starting or ending at 1:00pm, for example).

This is a checkbox which calls some javascript. When form is submitted, the data is send via POST to a php script that emails the information and also to a php script that inserts the data into a mySQL database.

When the checkbox is checked, i.e. 'Yes', the email that is sent includes the POST field 'Yes' into the email. However, regardless of the selection the database always add a '0' zero to the mySQL column - how can I get it to POST 'Yes' to database when 'Yes' is selected, everything else is working fine.

Help is appreciated, code is below :)

*html form*

```
<input type = "checkbox" name="halfClass" id="halfClass" value="Yes, I have half hour classes." style="width: 50px" onclick = "instructions(true)" >Yes<label style="width: 320px"><strong>Do you have some classes on the half hour?</strong></label></div>
```

*php send email*

```
$halfClass = $_POST['halfClass'];

$message = <<<EOD
<strong>$halfClass</strong> <br> <br />
EOD;
```

*php submit to db*

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO my_awesome_table (halfClass) VALUES ('$halfClass')";
```

[Image: What the Database Table shows :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRMJA.jpg)

Comment: how do these documents link together? are both the `php send email` script and `php submit to db` script being included in the same place? is the send email script being ran first? My guess is that `$halfClass` doesn't exist when you go to write it to the database, resulting in a `NULL` return which is `0` in your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the table's datatype? It might be because the datatype is numeric instead of string. Use varchar to fix if it's not varchar already.

Comment: Silly error - thank you everyone! It was int(3) so I've changed it to VARCHAR and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Check the datatype of your `halfClass` column. If it is a numeric type change it to a [string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html) type.

Answer (score 0):

If `halfClass` is an *integer* type then use:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO my_awesome_table (halfClass) VALUES (".$halfClass.")";
```

Or if `halfClass` is of *varchar* type, then use:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO my_awesome_table (halfClass) VALUES ('". $halfClass. "')";
```